# How to get auto code completion / intellisense of definitelyTyped "declare module" in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, webstorm, jsdoc, code-completion, definitelytyped

I use WebStorm, and write a nodeJS app.
enabled node js support ('Node.js Core library is enabled' option)
imported and enabled definitelyTyped: node-DefinitelyTyped
*(.WebStorm2016.2/config/javascript/extLibs/http_github.com_borisyankov_DefinitelyTyped_raw_master_node_node.d.ts)*

for example i want intellisence for `http.ServerResponse`
in the .d.ts file i have things like:

```
declare module "http" {
//...
  export interface ServerResponse extends events.EventEmitter, stream.Writable {
    //...
    writeHead(statusCode: number, headers?: any): void;
    //...
  }
}
```

now i want to get the method autocomplition in my js code:

```
/**
 * @param {http.ServerResponse} response such jsdoc does not work, what type is it?
 */
function handleResponse(response){
  response.writeHead(200); //here i want the autocompletion
}
```

**Question:** how to document the js / use .d.ts to get the right code-completion?

Comment: When working on Node.js it's recommended to enable Node.js Core library in Preferences | Languages and Frameworks | Node.js and npm instead of using node.d.ts.

Comment: @EkaterinaPrigara thanks. it is enabled. question updated.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the parameter(response).

`/**
 * @param {http.ServerResponse} response Now it should work
 */
...`

Comment: Yes, sorry my mistake. Question updated. But is still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
/**
 * @param {module:http.ServerResponse} 
 */
```